# Change package source when publishing on Rstudio Connect `https` vs `http'

Tags: r, rstudio

Rstudio Connect server is not able to install packages from https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES.rds  Our RSConnect admins says its not working because using `https` over proxy and the curl command executed in the background.
Looks like if I can somehow specify so that RSConnect uses `http` instead of `https` it can help, but I don't know how.
Is there a way admin can change it for every user so that RSConnect by default tries a specific mirror/url for packages

Comment: Is that something Rstudio support can't help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after almost giving up on this, just found the solution where I did not expect.
I did not think it has anything to do with settings on Rstudio on my computer.
I still did it and it worked. There is a checkbox in package management for disabling secure download method for http. I did not think this will affect how the Rstudio Connect behaves but I guess this get transported with the deploy bundle.

[image]